# How to pad missing columns in csv file with commas at the end

Tags: bash, csv, awk, sed

I have a CSV file with a variable number of 1-4 of the last 4 columns filled in. However, the rows missing values are not padded with commas, and thus programs fail to interpret the CSV correctly. How do I do add the missing commas at the end? Keep in mind this is a VERY large CSV file(500m+ lines, 200+gb), so it needs to be efficient.

Example of incorrect file:

```
col1,col2,col3,col4
val2,val3,val5,val6
val2
val2,val3
val2,val4,val8,val9
```

Example of desired result:

```
col1,col2,col3,col4
val2,val3,val5,val6
val2,,,
val2,val3,,
val2,val4,val8,val9
```

Comment: We encourage questioners to show what they have tried so far to solve the problem themselves.

Answer (score 4):

Force 4 columns with GNU `awk`:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} {NF=4; print}' file
```

Output:

```
col1,col2,col3,col4
val2,val3,val5,val6
val2,,,
val2,val3,,
val2,val4,val8,val9
```

See: [8 Powerful Awk Built-in Variables – **FS**, **OFS**, RS, ORS, NR, **NF**, FILENAME, FNR](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/01/8-powerful-awk-built-in-variables-fs-ofs-rs-ors-nr-nf-filename-fnr/)

Comment: That'll work with any POSIX awk, not just gawk. The effect of increasing the value of NF is defined by POSIX (add empty fields), it's just decreasing it that isn't.

Answer (score 2):

Using [Miller](https://miller.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installing-miller/) and running

```
mlr --csv --ragged cat input.csv >output.csv
```

you have

```
col1,col2,col3,col4
val2,val3,val5,val6
val2,,,
val2,val3,,
val2,val4,val8,val9
```

Answer (score 0):

If number of columns is etched in stone to be 4 then you might use following GNU `sed`, let `file.txt` content be

```
col1,col2,col3,col4
val2,val3,val5,val6
val2
val2,val3
val2,val4,val8,val9
val10,val11,val12
```

then

```
sed -e 's/^\([^,]*\)$/\1,,,/' -e 's/^\([^,]*,[^,]*\)$/\1,,/' -e 's/^\([^,]*,[^,]*,[^,]*\)$/\1,/' file.txt
```

output

```
col1,col2,col3,col4
val2,val3,val5,val6
val2,,,
val2,val3,,
val2,val4,val8,val9
val10,val11,val12,
```

Explanation: I prepare 3 expression here, which are arranged so for each line at most 1 of them will be used. 1st describe case with single field (no `,` in line) which lead to replacing line by line followed by `,,,` (i.e. appending `,,,`), 2nd describe case with 2 fields (single `,`) which cause addition of `,,` and 3rd case with 3 fields (two `,`) which cause addition of `,`.

*(note: I added additional line in file for testing case with 3 columns)*

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/$/,,,/;s/,//4g' file
```

Add three commas to the end of the line and then delete the fourth or more commas.